# magento remove block in layout.xml

Tags: xml, magento, layout, block

I have tier pricing set up for some items. This template is used on the product view page: catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml. I am trying to remove this by editing layout.xml with no success. How can I remove this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove it via layout update. You will have to edit `catalog/product/view.phtml` file and comment out `$this->getTierPriceHtml()` line.

`getTierPriceHtml` is also called in following template files:

```
bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml
bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml
catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way you can do is copy the catalog.xml from base layouts, copy it in your current theme's layout folder. In catalog_product_view handle, comment out line from:

```
<action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>
```

to:

```
<!--<action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>-->
```

This should work! :)

Comment: thank you for this suggestion! i tried it but strangely the block still appears on the page. any ideas?

Comment: yes and i checked it using a different browser but it was still there

Comment: You can check : 1) Enable template hints from backend and check to make sure if the content you are looking is inside tierprice.phtml. 2) Go to terminal and grep -R "tierprice.phtml" inside app/design/frontend. Check all the entries layout, check if anything is missed to comment/remove. 3) Check file permissions of the catalog.xml you have copied in your custom theme, if is does not have permissions, it will take from base and the block will still be visible